# xclip gives `Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0` in tmux session in Ubuntu VirtualBox VM

Tags: ssh, tmux, x11-forwarding, xclip

I'm attempting to use xclip in a tmux session in my Ubuntu VirtualBox VM for some copy/paste keybindings, but keep getting the same error message.

I have XQuartz installed on my host machine:

```
ysim:~$ which xquartz
/opt/X11/bin/xquartz
ysim:~$ echo $DISPLAY
/tmp/launch-N0023n/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

I have `ForwardX11 yes` set in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host vm
ForwardX11 yes
```

In my VM too, in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

When I'm ssh'ed in my VM, xclip works fine when I'm *not* in a tmux session:

```
$ echo hello | xclip
$ xclip -o
hello
```

But errors when I'm in one:

```
$ echo hello | xclip
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

Any ideas why this might be the case?

**Update:** Now it seems to only happen if I exit a tmux session, then create a new one.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue or found any solution?

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error. I fixed it by exiting my tmux session, disconnecting my ssh session and reconnecting (opening another terminal window).

I was ssh'd into a server, but if you're just using a local VM, I think exiting your tmux session and reopening terminal should have the same effect.

Comment: The problem still exists in tmux v2.6, the workaround is still working. Is this a tmux bug? Anyone has ideas? btw, I've been using tmux for at least 1.5 years, this is my first time encountering this problem, which is pretty weired.